# What is the machine name for the Date Posted?

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm using Views and have it set to fields. Can anyone tell me what the machine name of `Content: Post date` is? I used `Time ago` in my selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the 'ID' of the `Content: Post date` in Views, it is: `created`

You can find this under the `Theme: Information` link under the 'Advanced' settings block (in D7/Views 3) or the 'Basic settings' block (in D6/Views 2).  After clicking that link, find the name of the field and find the ID in parenthesis next to the field name.

Example: In this case you should find `Field Content: Post date (ID: created)`

Answer (score 1):

Another smart trick to know identifiers is the following.

Hover your field title (e.g. "Taxonomy: Term") from your view setting, and focus on the status bar of your browser.

In my case, I get `http://example.com/#overlay=%3Fq%3Dadmin/structure/views/nojs/config-item/my_view/page/field/name`.

Look into the last 4 items:

- my_view: View Identifier
- page: Display Identifier
- name: Field Identifier